# How do you convert a Javascript keyCode to a charCode?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keycode, fromcharcode

In a Javascript **keyboard event**, a code is given for the key pressed, however, *it is not an ASCII or UTF-8 character code,* rather, it is a code for the keyboard key. Sometimes the keyCodes happen to match up with ASCII/UTF-8 codes, sometimes they do not.

Is there a way, given a Javascript key code, (accessed via `e.keyCode` or `e.which`) to get the corresponding ASCII or UTF-8 charcode?

[Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsh6e5f9/) to demonstrate what I mean, or run the snippet below.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {

  document.querySelector(".key").innerHTML = e.key;
  document.querySelector(".keyCode").innerHTML = e.keyCode;
  document.querySelector(".UTF").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

});
```

```css
code {
  background-color: #e2aec8ab;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  min-height: 1em;
  min-width: .2em;
  margin: 0 .1em;
}

.output {
  margin: 2em;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 250, 230, .3);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
Type here. Try some alpha letters as well as special keys like <code>`</code>
<code>-</code>
<code>=</code>
<code>[</code>
<code>]</code>
<code>[ENTER]</code>
<code>;</code>
<code>'</code>


<div class="output">
  You typed <code class="key"></code> which is Javascript <b></b>keyCode</b> <code class="keyCode"></code>, in UTF that would be <code class="UTF"></code>
</div>
```

Two examples:

1. Type `2` on the keyboard
2. Capture the event. `event.keyCode` is 50.
3. The UTF character 50 is `2` ([DIGIT TWO](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0032/index.htm))

but:

1. Type `[` on the keyboard
2. Capture the event. `event.keyCode` is 219.
3. The UTF character 219 is `Û` ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb/index.htm))
4. The charcode I wish the event contained is `91` which corresponds to [LEFT SQUARE BRACKET](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005b/index.htm).

How do I convert Javascript keyCodes (e.g. `219`) into UTF-8 charCodes (e.g. `91`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just want to say, this question became a fun learning adventure. But....

### You're using deprecated APIs.

As it turns out [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) has been deprecated for a while. Because it uses the decimal version of ASCII. The correct code to use is actually `event.Code`. But that's not what you're after.

To get the ascii number, you can just use `event.key.charCodeAt()` This does have some flaws as it will report `S` when you hit shift. But you can use `event.location` to figure out if the key is a special control key. Zero is standard keys and 1-3 are special locations (I think).

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {

  document.querySelector(".key").innerHTML = e.key;
  document.querySelector(".keyCode").innerHTML = e.code;
  document.querySelector(".ascii").innerHTML = e.key.charCodeAt()
  document.querySelector(".UTF").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(event.key.charCodeAt());

});
```

```css
code {
  background-color: #e2aec8ab;
  ;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  min-height: 1em;
  min-width: .2em;
  margin: 0 .1em;
}

.output {
  margin: 2em;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 250, 230, .3);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
Type here. Try some alpha letters as well as special keys like <code>`</code>
<code>-</code>
<code>=</code>
<code>[</code>
<code>]</code>
<code>[ENTER]</code>
<code>;</code>
<code>'</code>


<div class="output">
  You typed <code class="key"></code> which is Javascript <b>keyCode</b> <code class="keyCode"></code>, in ASCII that would be <code class="ascii"> </code> which is <code class="UTF"></code>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I don't know why I didn't think to just read the UTF code of `event.key` since I have it right there! Very smart! I went back and was looking at the MDN docs for `e.charCode` (which is also, unfortunately, deprecated but would have given the UTF-8 code!) and it actually says right at the top of that doc: "Do not use this property, as it is deprecated. Use the key property instead." So if I had just read thoroughly I could have taken that hint!